# How to make an AppleScript that copies HTML source code from webpages?

Tags: java, javascript, html, eclipse, applescript

I just want to know how can I make an AppleScript that copies the source code of an open webpage to the clipboard

OR

Can I make a script that searches for a specified class on the webpage and copies it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Here, we expect questions to be supported by code, original research, examples, and other information about the specific problem you're facing. This is not a "give me teh codez" site to simply hand code over to you. Please [read and complete this checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) before asking questions.

Comment: It would help us to help you if you gave a bit more detail. I don't even know what language you're currently asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to get HTML from a webpage and copy to the clipboard is fairly simple in AppleScript.

```
set theHTML to do shell script "curl -L http://twitter.com | pbcopy"
```

Comment: Yes I'm talking about AppleScript. okay looks good, but what if the link is in the clipboard, how can I make it gets the link from clipboard? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Like this: http://d.chend.me/XZ8p